# Open Credit Card Merchant Data

Tags: finance

I'm looking for open data around credit card merchants, similar to what Mastercard provides with their [Merchant API](https://developer.mastercard.com/merchant-identifier/documentation/api-reference). Some of this data seems to be findable online ([example for Amazon](https://cardcharge.report/merchant/amazon-mktplace-pmts-amzn-com-bill-wa/) and then [another with many examples](https://www.vcharges.com/)), but I can't find any good datasets or APIs. Mastercard API is not available as it's not free. Any other ideas?